# How can I represent these three words conceptually, without using words?

Tags: word, puzzle-creation

I'm looking to represent three separate words without using words. The goal is for somebody to be able to guess each word from the representation.

For example, I'm looking to represent the word "ambiguity" with the definition: "the multiple meanings, either intentional or unintentional, of a word, phrase, sentence, or passage." I might, for example, represent ambiguity with this image of an animal that can be either a duck or a rabbit depending on the angle at which you view the image.

The other words I'm looking to represent are "analogy" and "anaphora." Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! How exactly is this related to puzzle-solving, or puzzles in general?

Comment: @Deusovi "The goal is for somebody to be able to guess each word from the [pictorial] representation." So it looks like he's asking for help with constructing a visual riddle, which I *think* is on-topic? (Also worth noting - OP was redirected here from English.SE.)

Comment: creating puzzles is on-topic according to https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic , and this looks like Graham is creating a rebus

Comment: I'm not sure this is a visual riddle, though. Riddles are a particular type of puzzle where indirect clues about an object are given, and this wouldn't be one. If anything, it could be a piece of a rebus. But you'd need units of more than one picture, some sort of combination using wordplay, and shorter (more combineable) words  - *none* of which this seems to have.

Comment: @Deusovi , we can suggest OP to use multiple pictures to represent the words they want.

Comment: Would the solver know that the word is going to start with an A? If not, it might be difficult to come up with a pictorial representation of analogy that is not also simile or similarity, and one of anaphora that is not merely pronoun.

Comment: Those are pretty difficult words to try to represent un-ambiguous-ly with just pictures

Comment: Wait I can think of a slightly risque interpretation of analogy, but I'll probably get flagged for posting it...

Comment: @NL628 you'll get away by putting it behind spoilers and warning about the content.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis No, the solver wouldn't. No words or letters can be used, and no hints can be given with words or letters. However, I can use sounds, mathematical expressions/symbols, and numbers.

Comment: @Graham Which definition of anaphora?

Comment: @called2voyage the repetition of words or phrases, typically for an emphatic effect. P.S. the users here are far nicer and far less pretentious and arrogant than those of the English Usage stackexchange.

Comment: @Graham Welcome to Puzzling! Looks like you've stumped the puzzlers here (for now), but judging from the 6 upvotes, the question is right at home here. Your own answer is excellent.

Comment: @Lawrence Hey, thanks! That's the nicest thing anyone's said to me in a while!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out.

"Anaphora" would be the repetition of words or phrases, so I illustrated the ten commandments (the tablets) and drew three lines for commandments 1 through 3, respectively.
e.g.

1. **_ _** ___ (thou shall not)
2. **_ _** ___ (thou shall not)
3. **_ _** ___ (thou shall not)

Someone ended up guessing it.

For "ambiguity," I used the duck/rabbit painting that I posted above.

For "analogy," I illustrated a computer mouse with a line going right, where i illustrated a real mouse.

All three were guessed. Thanks, folks.